# Python unidecode function opening lists/documents

Tags: python, text, unicode

How can I open document as Unicode? 
I have txt file which contains foreign characters. I need to open it word by word using this unidecode function. 
I am getting error saying -- TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

```
import os
import re
import unidecode

def splitToWords(stringOfWords):
    retVal = re.split('; |;|, |,|\*|\n|\. |\.|-| |\"',stringOfWords)
    while '' in retVal:
        retVal.remove('')
    [val.lower() for val in retVal]
    return retVal
....
       with open(file,"r") as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        file_content = splitToWords(file_content)
        for word in file_content
        word = unidecode.unidecode(word)
        f.close()
```

Comment: can you please send your input ?

Comment: What do you mean *"open document as Unicode"*? Presumably the problem here is that your `import` is inconsistent with your attempted use - try e.g. `from unidecode import ...`.

Comment: can you please post the code of `splitToWords`

Comment: word = word.encode("utf-16") will solve your problem

Comment: Fix the copy-paste error in your code. Try to [create a minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post a full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please check the below code, is this you wanted ?

```
unicodestring = "u there"
utf8tostring = unicodestring.encode("utf-16")
print utf8tostring
```

code refered from the following website https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/ch01s22.html

Comment: (1) `"abc"` is a bytestring in Python 2 (Python version is infered from the `print` statement). It is not Unicode. You should a `u''` prefix to make it a Unicode literal (2) print Unicode instead of bytes otherwise you'll get a mojibake in any environment that has character encoding different from utf-16 (most of them) i.e., you should not call `.encode()` here (3) it is unrelated to OP's question

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
# you have to import unidecode function first
from unidecode import unidecode

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
       # this will split a line to words and decode them.
       # you don't have to close() the file, "with open()" does that for you.
       decoded_words = [unidecode(word) for word in line.split()]
```

Comment: you don't need *"to import unidecode function first"* e.g., `import unidecode; unidecode.unidecode(u'\N{EURO SIGN}')` works just fine.